# Necesito Ayuda Por favor algo estoy haciendo mal en phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Veran tengo la siguiente web php:

```
<?php
  // primero hay que incluir la clase phpmailer para poder instanciar
  //un objeto de la misma
  require "includes/class.phpmailer.php";

  //instanciamos un objeto de la clase phpmailer al que llamamos 
  //por ejemplo mail
  $mail = new phpmailer();

  //Definimos las propiedades y llamamos a los métodos 
  //correspondientes del objeto mail

  //Con PluginDir le indicamos a la clase phpmailer donde se 
  //encuentra la clase smtp que como he comentado al principio de 
  //este ejemplo va a estar en el subdirectorio includes
  $mail->PluginDir = "includes/";

  //Con la propiedad Mailer le indicamos que vamos a usar un 
  //servidor smtp
  $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

  //Asignamos a Host el nombre de nuestro servidor smtp
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

  //Le indicamos que el servidor smtp requiere autenticación
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

  //Le decimos cual es nuestro nombre de usuario y password
  $mail->Username = "mi_correo@gmail.com"; 
  $mail->Password = "123456";

  //Indicamos cual es nuestra dirección de correo y el nombre que 
  //queremos que vea el usuario que lee nuestro correo
  $mail->From = "mi_correo@gmail.com";
  $mail->FromName = "Pedro Perez";

  //el valor por defecto 10 de Timeout es un poco escaso dado que voy a usar 
  //una cuenta gratuita, por tanto lo pongo a 30  
  $mail->Timeout=30;

  //Indicamos cual es la dirección de destino del correo
  $mail->AddAddress("recive_el_correo_enviado@hotmail.com");

  //Asignamos asunto y cuerpo del mensaje
  //El cuerpo del mensaje lo ponemos en formato html, haciendo 
  //que se vea en negrita
  $mail->Subject = "Prueba de phpmailer";
  $mail->Body = "<b>Mensaje de prueba mandado con phpmailer en formato html</b>";

  //Definimos AltBody por si el destinatario del correo no admite email con formato html 
  $mail->AltBody = "Mensaje de prueba mandado con phpmailer en formato solo texto";

  //se envia el mensaje, si no ha habido problemas 
  //la variable $exito tendra el valor true
  $exito = $mail->Send();

  //Si el mensaje no ha podido ser enviado se realizaran 4 intentos mas como mucho 
  //para intentar enviar el mensaje, cada intento se hara 5 segundos despues 
  //del anterior, para ello se usa la funcion sleep 
  $intentos=1; 
  while ((!$exito) && ($intentos < 5)) {
    sleep(5);
        //echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $exito = $mail->Send();
        $intentos=$intentos+1;  

   }


   if(!$exito)
   {
    echo "Problemas enviando correo electrónico a ".$valor;
    echo "<br/>".$mail->ErrorInfo;  
   }
   else
   {
    echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
   } 

?>
```

dentro de Xampp en este lado:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

quite comentario **date.timezone = America/New_York** osea el punto y comoa al principio **;** hasta hay todo "Bien" ya no me da error zona horaria.

por otro lado configure el link [este](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps?pli=1) **segui las instruciones del Paso 1 solamente.**

Active la casilla App del [link](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps?pli=1) donde dice textualmente: **Acceso de apps menos seguras**

aun asi me da error:

**Problemas enviando correo electrónico a 
The following From address failed: mi_correo@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected**

no se que ando haciendo mal

Adjunto los archivos php en mediafire: [Link esta en ZIP](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wd9qv6so9os5i1u/email.zip/file)

PD: el Correo NO existe lo modifique el objetivo de subir los PhP es que alguien me corrija donde esta el error Gracias de antemano.

Comment: A simple vista veo es que llamas a la clase como `phpmailer` cuando es `PHPMailer`, los nombres de las cases son sensibles a minusculas y mayusculas.

Comment: y esos archivosd del media fire son los que debo tener? pues es lo que tengo y no me funciona no se por que